# Get and transmit form input value from controller to another

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, controller

I have some troubles with my Symfony Form.
In my first controller, I render a form like this:

```
    $annonce = new Annonce();
    $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($annonce);
    $formBuilder
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('valider', 'submit');
    $form = $formBuilder->getForm();

    $request = $this->get('request');

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);

        $response = $this->forward('ProjectMainBundle:Commande:new', array(
            'annonce' => $form["title"]
        ));

        return $response;
    }
```

And I print the form in the view like this:

```
<form method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_row(form.title, {'attr': {'value': entity.mytext }}) }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

That's give:

```
<form method="post">
    <div>
        <label class="required" for="form_title">Title</label>
        <input id="form_title" type="text" value="11" required="required" name="form[title]">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
</form>
```

So when I submit it, I got the warning

```
"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Symfony\Component\Form\Form could not be converted to string"
```

I simply want to redirect to the controller "newAction" (that's work), but with the value of the input of my form !

```
<input id="form_title" type="text" value="11" required="required" name="form[title]">
```

It seems to I return the form object with

```
$response = $this->forward('ProjectMainBundle:Commande:new', array(
    'annonce' => $form["title"]
));
```

But how return just the value of the input of the form ?

Big thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling $annonce->getTitle() instead of using $form["title"]. 
After calling "$form->bind($request)" your $annonce object should have the title entered in the form.